# why Hahn-Banach theorem is used?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some confusion regarding the given below  solution

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a set of linearly independent elements of a normed vector space $X$. Let $c_1,\dots,c_n \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that there exists $f\in X^\ast$ such that $f(x_i)=c_i$.

**Solution** :
consider $M = span\{x_1,...,x_n\}$, which is a subspace of $X$. Any $x\in M$ can be written $x=\sum_1^n \lambda_k x_k$, for some $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$. Define $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $f(x_i)=c_i$ for $i=1,...,n$. Then $$|f(x)| = |\sum_1^n \lambda_k c_k | < \infty,$$

Hence, for any $x \in M$ we have $|f(x)| < \infty$. Since $f$ is bounded there exists a constant $C$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C\|x\|$ for all $x \in M$, where $\| \cdot \|$ is the norm on $X$. If we define $p(x) = C\|x \|$, then it will clearly be a semi-norm on $X$ and we can use the Hahn-Banach Theorem to get the desired result!

**My confusion**: why   Hahn-Banach theorem  is used in the given solution because in the solution it's already defined that $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $f(x_i)=c_i$ for $i=1,...,n$.

I don't see  any  role  of Hahn-Banach theorem in the given solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Hahn-Banach to extend $f$ to all of $X$. Otherwise $f$ would only be defined on $M$ and hence not be in $X^*$.

If you were in a Hilbert space, you could avoid Hahn-Banach by extending your functional by zero on the orthogonal complement. But in general normed spaces we have no clue how to extend a functional in a constructive way (such that it is still continuous).

Answer (score 2):

Showing that there exists a linear map $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ with $f(x_i) =c_i$ is quite straightforward: consider $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ and extend it to a basis of $X$. Then define the functional you want in the obvious way.

However, you will need Hahn-Banach theorem to ensure that you can choose an extension that remains continuous.